# Setting up an API in Power BI to pull data from website

Tags: python, api, powerbi-desktop

I'm relatively new to python and API's. Basically, I have a form in Wufoo that I am currently manually exporting the data from into an excel document so that builds a Power BI report. I have been trying to set up a web connection directly to Wufoo so I no longer have to do the manual data pull.

I have tried using the get data from Web in Power BI and entering the URL: http://{subdomain}.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/{identifier}/fields.{format})  updating the subdomain and using the form's hash as the identifier, and setting the format to json

But get an error:
"(400): Your request has been rejected.  Please make this request via HTTPS."

I built some code in Python (I'm using version 3.9.5) below, and while I am able to get it to pull the data and print it out in my code editor (Komodo Edit), but no data comes up in the navigator. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import urllib.request
import json

base_url = 'https://ewolford.wufoo.com/api/v3/'
username = 'API KEY'
password = 'password'

password_manager = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, base_url, username, password)
handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

response = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url+'forms/hash/entries.json?sort=EntryId&sortDirection=DESC')

data = json.load(response)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a last line to print a `pandas.dataframe` instead. From Microsoft doc. (emphasis mine):

> The Power BI Python integration requires the installation of two Python packages:

> **Pandas**. A software library for data manipulation and analysis. It offers data structures and operations for manipulating numerical tables and time series. ***Your imported data must be in a pandas data frame***. A data frame is a two-dimensional data structure. For example, data is aligned in a tabular fashion in rows and columns.

```
import pandas as pd

{your code here}

data=json.load(response)

table=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(table)
```

Comment: Wonderful! I knew I was missing something, worked perfectly. Now I have to figure out why it is only pulling the last 25 records instead of the entire dataset.

Comment: If the question is successfully answered, I recommend to accept it as closed and then open a new question.